# Qiskit Runtime: What are the units of job.result().time_taken? Seconds, milli-seconds, micro-seconds?

Tags: qiskit

```
job = execute(qwalk_circuit, backend='ibmq_16_melbourne', shots=1000)

results = job.result()

time = job.result().time_taken
```

What are the units of time? And where is this stated in the documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run a job and compare the output of `time_taken`  to the runtime in IBM quantum experience, but I cannot find any relation between the two.

Comment: Looks like missing from the docs indeed: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Counts.html#qiskit.result.Counts

Answer (score 1):

As @3yakuya has said, this is missing from the documentation.

The best I could find is a Qiskit tutorial (version 0.37.1) which uses the parameter. According to [this tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/7_matrix_product_state_method.html) (see the 3rd code cell), the unit of time appears to be **seconds**:

[image: Screenshot from the Qiskit tutorial]

Comment: I tried a job that took many minutes and another that took seconds to run and the `time_taken’ was pretty similar. I wonder what is it actually measuring